# When the following limit is zero

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that $f\in L_1(\mathbb{R})\cap L_2(\mathbb{R})$ and $g(y)=\int_\mathbb{R}f(x)f(x-y) dx$. I would like to know when
$$\lim_{\|f\|\to 0}\frac{\left\|g\right\|}{\|f\|}=0,$$
where $\|\|$ is the $L_2$ norm

By the Young's inequlality
$$\|g\|\leq \|f\|_1\|f\|,$$
so the question reduces to showing that
$$\lim_{\|f\|\to 0}\|f\|_1=0,$$
and I'm not sure if this is the case.

Answer (score 1):

What is the parameter for the family of $f$'s?  If there is a limiting function say $f_0$, with $||f_0||_1=0$, then $|f_0|=0$ almost everywhere and the $L_2$ norm $=0$.